# Could not resolve placeholder error when @ConfigurationProperties and @Value are used together

Tags: spring, annotations

We have a springboot project MainProject which uses yaml The main config class looks something like this

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.xyz.platform"})
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableHystrix
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/beans-xyz-abc.xml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="config.prefix")
@Validated

// this is an external sdk jar. this contains more beans and used @Value 
// annotaion for property binding
@Import(SDKConfiguration.class)
public class AuthorizationDelegationWsApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
// class code here
}
```

The above config class imports another external SDK config class using @Import. The external class SDKConfiguration looks something like this

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:client.properties" }, ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SDKConfiguration {
    @Value("${host:}")
    private String host;
// class code here
}
```

The external SDK has the client.properties file in class path and also 'host' property in it.
Before I added the external config class, all went fine. But after I added it, service startup fails with below error

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'host' in value "${host}""
```

I tried editing the external SDK by moving it to @ConfigurationProperties instead of @Value. It doesn't throw any exception but I get NPE as 'host' is not set.

I tried changing 'host' to 'config.prefix.host'. But no use.

I think the issue is because of using both @Value and @ConfigurationProperties. But I couldn't find any documentation anywhere.

Please let me know what options I can try.

Comment: Hi Sukhesh, See if below link could help: https://www.java2novice.com/spring-boot/configurationproperties-vs-value/

Comment: i checked the articles. couldn't get solution to this problem. thanks for the info though